# Can sp_BlitzFirst pass the @ExpertMode parameter to sp_BlitzWho

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sp-blitzfirst

When running sp_blitzFirst @expertmode = 1 the first result set(result set of sp_blitzwho)does not return nearly as many columns and it does in [Brent's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQcdbbmTqX4). With a little troubleshooting it was uncovered that the reason this is happening is because the calling stored procedure is not passing @expertMode = 1 to sp_blitzWho.
To prove that i can run sp_blitzWho and pass @expertMode = 1 in which case the etire result set is returned.

So my question is: Was there a change to latest version of these stored procedures?
Where can i find the version that work like the one Brent displays in his video?
Thank you for looking in to this.
Best Regards.

Comment: You can [report bugs here](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues) for `sp_BlitzFirst` (or any of the first responder toolkit). You can also browse the [change history](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/commits/dev/sp_BlitzFirst.sql) and [contribute a fix](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/CONTRIBUTING.md) if you're able to identify and address the underlying issue yourself. Welcome to the network :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution is (possibly) related to a third-party tool. Please open up an issue via the Github Repository for [SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues).

Answer (score 1):

You're watching a 4-year-old video on YouTube, and sp_BlitzFirst no longer works that way.

If you want to run sp_BlitzWho with @ExpertMode = 1, your best bet is to go ahead and call it directly.

Comment: I would like to run sp_blitzfirst with expertmode = 1 and i can but it does not return the result set you are showing in the video because expertmode = 1 is not passed to sp_blitsWho. To remediate i would have to rewrite all the temp tables. Alternatively, if possible could you point me to the version of code you run in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQcdbbmTqX4

Comment: Ah, see the date on that video? It's 4 years ago. sp_BlitzFirst no longer works that way. If you'd like it to, you can change the default starting parameter for sp_BlitzWho so that it defaults to ExpertMode = 1 instead of 0.